# How to configure JMeter Thread group for 1 million request in 10 seconds?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing, gatling

I want to run a Load test on my Production server to verify that the server can handle 1 million requests per 10 seconds using JMeter. How to configure JMeter Thread group for 1 million request in 10 seconds? How many client I need to do this test?

Please share your valuable experience if you have experience doing this type of load test.

Answer (score 0):

**First, you should  ensure you really need 1 million requests in 10 seconds (what kind of site are you testing ?).**

Then if you want to use JMeter, ensure:

- You use last version
- You tune memory correctly
- You will certainly have to use distributed testing if not using Cloud
- Follow best practices

> http://www.dzone.com/links/r/see_how_to_make_jmeter_run_thousands_of_threads_w.html (Disclaimer : I'm the writer of this)
>
> http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

- You might try [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) to make a kind of Barrier
- Alternatively you can try "Delay thread until creation"
- And finally try a Cloud solution to get to this load, see this french blog on all kind of issues you will face in all fields (not only load software):

> http://blog.milamberspace.net/index.php/2012/07/14/rapport-de-tres-gros-test-de-charge-avec-la-solution-blazemeter-1161.html)

*But I never tried up to this load, so I cannot tell if it will work* and it is kind of unexplored field

Comment: My Client said they might have 1 million user and They can start accessing the application right after the site get launched. I want to take a precaution to mitigate the risk of getting the server down.

Comment: Look at this : http://www.webperformance.com/library/tutorials/CalculateNumberOfLoadtestUsers/

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish this using Gatling and scaling out to several machines that would run the test in parallel. in the end Gatling can aggregate the results into 1 report.

Gatling documentation dosent provide much info for this :

http://gatling.io/docs/1.5.6/user_documentation/cookbooks/scaling_out.html

but you can check my blog post to see how this can be done (ive wrote a script for this purpose)

Blog - http://www.nimrodstech.com/gatling-cluster-load-testing/

Gist - https://gist.github.com/Nimrod007/5cfed34eeffedfd7ec76

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you'd better look onto another, more suitable tool for such kind of scenario,
e.g. [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)

- [Tsung homepage](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Tsung @ github](https://github.com/processone/tsung)
- [Scaling to 30K: Tsung](http://attentionshard.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/scaling-to-30k-tsung/)

or at least [Gatling](http://gatling-tool.org/) instead:

- [Gatling homepage](http://gatling-tool.org/)
- [Gatling: scaling out](https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Scaling-out)

Perhaps if you would like to use jmeter in any case you can look onto [BlazeMeterLoad Testing Cloud](http://blazemeter.com/features) solution.

Comment: I agree you should consider another tool for such a scenario, and Gatling is a good tool for that, even if it's never been pushed to such extend. You'll probably have to scale out, so you might consider a PAAS, such as Gridinit that supports also Gatling. http://gridinit.com